How can this chrome plugin instantly update the CSS without reloading?
Currently, there is a chrome plugin called "User CSS" which allows you to write custom CSS to update anysite in real time as you type the css code.
I am only interested in how the plugin is managing to do this. I want to create a similar plugin that allows me to instantly modify the CSS of a site as I am typing.
Currently, my plugin can update the CSS of a page by ONLY pushing the CSS code (after I typed it) to the DOM via the sendMessage Chrome API but that requires me to trigger a workflow everytime.
Of course, this is only happening client side as a rendered preview of the site. It's not affecting the real code.
How can I recreate the same feaure as UserCSS to instantly update the CSS of a page instantly as I am typing the css?
LINK TO "USER CSS" - CHROME PLUGIN ON THE WEBSTORE

Simply set textContent of the style element to the new text if you use a content script. It's as simple as that, so without seeing your code it's unclear if that's the only problem. You can also debug the code of any extension in the built-in devtools debugger and see what it's doing.
